# Is a global boolean variable reliable during global destruction?

Tags: c++, global-variables, destructor, object-lifetime

If I have a simple data type as a global variable -- like a boolean flag; specifically, something that doesn't have a destructor -- does that variable remain reliable even during global destruction? Or is that not guaranteed?

For example, would the result for the following code be well-defined?

**Flag.h:**

```
void SetFlagState(bool flag);
bool GetFlagState();
```

**Flag.cpp:**

```
#include <Flag.h>
namespace { // local declarations
bool g_flag; 
}

void SetFlagState(bool flag)
{
    g_flag = flag;
}
bool GetFlagState()
{
    return g_flag;
}
```

**Main:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Flag.h>

class FlagChecker
{
public:
    ~FlagChecker()
    {
        std::cout << "Flag value: " << GetFlagState() << std::endl;
    }
};
FlagChecker g_FlagChecker; // global instance; dtor will be called on exit

int main()
{
    SetFlagState(true);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is safe. The lifetime of the storage is the duration of the program. The chief issue during that lifetime is with the moment of initialization (via your `g_Flagchecker`). As there's no such thing "de-initialization" for built-in types, your `g_flag` remains valid as long as there's code executing in your process.

Comment: Are you sure, if `g_flag`was a regular class, we would have problem for sure. In the same way, it is unspecified which global would be initialized first.

Comment: @Jarod42: That's why i point out that there's no such thing as "de-ininitialization for built-in types". Classes do have destructors, and those are run prior to a clean exit.

Comment: I think the only question is whether it's guaranteed that "de-initialized" storage can't be used for anything else before the program exits completely. @MSalters says the lifetime includes the exit, so that sounds good :)